# Huge Memory Leaks with XMLHttp POST Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, memory-leaks

How can i avoid XHR POST Memory leak? I go through lots of web pages regarding XHR memory leak but there is no good solutions. My problem is almost similar to [this](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2013/02/08/)  That blog explains the problem but no solutions.

My Problem: 
I have a web app which Continuously send date to server (2Mb to 80Mb) and it will make 10 to 300 requests. It is POST request. for GET request no big problem like this.

How can i solve this?
Circular reference, Scope , closer etc i try but no success.
i try to use delete keyword for readystate change, delete previous xhr object , try to reuse xhr , xhr reference to null , changing coding patters etc

This is  the sample code. this is the functionality i need

```
 var base_string =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQUST01234567890!@#$%^&:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQUST01234567890!@#$%^&ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQUST01234567890!@#$%^&";
            base_string += base_string;  
            base_string += base_string; 
            base_string += base_string; 
            base_string += base_string;  
            base_string += base_string;  
            base_string += base_string;  
            base_string += base_string;  
            base_string += base_string; 
            base_string += base_string;  
            base_string += base_string;  
            base_string += base_string; 
            base_string += base_string;  
            base_string += base_string;  
            base_string += base_string;  
            base_string += base_string;  
            base_string += base_string;  
            base_string += base_string;  
            this.sampleData = base_string;
            var dataToSend = this.sampleData.substring( 0, 2000000 );



           this.xhr = [];
           this.xhr[0] = new XMLHttpRequest();
           function sendRequest (){
               var Self = this;
               Self.xhr[0].onload = function (test) {
                   sendRequest ();
               };

               Self.xhr[0].open("POST", "http://localhost/upload.php" + "?n=" +  Math.random(), true);
               Self.xhr[0].send(dataToSend);
           }
           sendRequest ();
```

How can i accomplish this without Memory leaks?

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to achieve with that odd looking sendRequest function - never seen anybody do that - what do you think its purpose is? - or the array, with a single element ... it's all bizarre code, that looks like it's designed to cause issues

Comment: purpose is to measure the upload speed of the connection

Comment: well, it doesn't do anything like that - not sure if it would cause an error or keep sending the data repeatedly ... oh, I see, it's supposed to send then when done, send again, infinitely

Comment: I also try if(Self.xhr.readyState == 4 && Self.xhr.status == 200){} No change!

Comment: So this function repeatedly sends a large POST request once the previous request has finished ... and you're wondering where the memory leak is ...

Comment: YES! after ready state = 4 GC should come and kill them right?

Comment: try it without the pointless `var Self` and the array of xhr (you only use 1 element) ... declare `var xhr = ` instead, and use `xhr.open` / `xhr.send` etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122471/discussion-between-vishnu-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: I already try that ZERO difference!

Comment: So you tried **cleaner** code, and decided to go with strange and pointless code instead ... each to their own, I guess

Comment: Trying unconventional things to solve a strange problem :( When i run your code https://postimg.org/image/x0zlg5bxh/ it will go up to 18 GB! or more .. i closed browser when it reached 18GB

Comment: so my code is **worse** ? interesting

Comment: OMG! i never said that! :) All i need is to avoid memory leak :) I have no problem with your code :)

Comment: no probs, it's not a "faster" leak or anything?

Comment: 18GB!!! damn!!! how much RAM do you have!!!

Comment: 16 GB ram! mid-2014 Retina macbook pro :) it is very fast less that 60 seconds it will cross 10GB

Comment: I think you should give a try if you have time. To full experience this :)

Comment: Have done so - even though I said I wouldn't :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for every request you send, you add a new onload handler.

```
Self.xhr[0].onload = function (test) {
    sendRequest ();
};
```

The old handler will not be deleted at this point and stays in memory. The garbage collector will not be able to free the memory.

In your case you only ever need one eventlistener, so i recommend moving the attachment of the listener out of the sendRequest function like so, and the memory leak should be gone.

```
this.xhr = [];
this.xhr[0] = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr[0].onload = function (test) {
    sendRequest ();
};
function sendRequest (){
    xhr[0].open("POST", "http://localhost/upload.php" + "?n=" +  Math.random(), true);
    xhr[0].send(dataToSend);
}
sendRequest ();
```

### EDIT: Version 2

i have tried another version which produces even better results. memory never surpasses 2.6G on my setup. Its a derivation of Jaromandas work.
It's basicly his version with an addition of `removeEventHandler` and `delete`

```
function sendRequest (){
function run(e){
  xhr.upload.removeEventListener('load',run)
  sendRequest()
}
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', run);
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:2345/" + "?n=" +  Math.random(), true);
xhr.send(dataToSend);
delete xhr
}
sendRequest ();
```

Comment: that's strange, for me it works well (Linux, Chrome, Node.js server, all on one maschine) Chrome's memory use goes up to around 4G then the garbage collection kicks in and it falls to around 2G the raises back to 4G an falls down again... keeps fluctuating forever, never going above 4G.

Comment: Sorry i tested it on Safari! it is still doing the same thing! Just watched 10GB+ Memory usage :). Yesterday i was trying different thing to solve this issue. and some solutions behaved like this. Firefox  went to 900Mb and came down to 400Mb! Chrome went to 2.34Gb and came down to 1.8Gb etc. but i thought it is still a Huge leak! Because a Dead simple Ajax post request need this amount of memory? So i think i am doing something wrong!

Comment: EDIT: Version 2
This is the better version! Firefox went to 10GB and came down to 600Mb! Chrome is 800 to 900 range!

Comment: Unfortunately safari is still doing the same!

Comment: removeEventListener is working very well on Windows 10 and Mac (Tested Chrome , Firefox  on both and Edge on W10 Safari on Mac)
ONLY SAFARI STILL CONTINUE BEHAVING LIKE MY ORIGINAL CODE
Everything else is behaving differently but better! Firefox on Mac went 10GB and go back to 600MB , Firefox on W10 wet to 3.5 GB and went back to 200!  What you think about safari? I think i am going to ignore safari! Continue my works!

Comment: What happens when you stop the requests? is the memory going down again? 
I would think, that your bandwidth-test isn't an infinite process anyways, and if everything is well when you stop the test, memory consumption is not such a big deal. Just Limit the total number of request and you will be fine anyways...

Answer (score 3):

continuously + size of request + amount of requests. I think you should not be using XHR for that situation. maybe WebRTC, Long Polling or Web Sockets. Even if you find a workaround to perform it in that way, this will not scale.

Answer (score 2):

Clean up your code - this should do the same thing without the bizarre and pointless use of Self, and the array ... it also re-initializes xhr

I've changed to add a listener to the upload load event - a quick test here seems to not leak (seems to)

```
// snip
this.sampleData = base_string;
var dataToSend = this.sampleData.substring( 0, 2000000 );

function sendRequest (){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        sendRequest ();
    });

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost/upload.php" + "?n=" +  Math.random(), true);
    xhr.send(dataToSend);
}
sendRequest ();
```

Comment: Turn off Javascript console for google chrome or firefox to execute this script faster .. and see the growth of memory in Your taskmanager

Comment: EventListener is not firing for me

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry i was testing this on a WebWroker setup. now i tested it on normal setup! EventListener is firing! but that HUGE LEAK is still there :(

Comment: wow, firefox showed what may have been a tiny leak compared to the original code - hard to say, because firefox is full of leaky little holes anyway

Comment: I used safari! The Modern IE 6 :)

Comment: See the magic of Safari! https://postimg.org/image/iovged40v/ Firefox went to 3.4 GB and stays around 1.4 to 2.7 Gb when running your code :) Google Chrome also went 2Gb+ Chrome is the least leaking browser :) Leaks depending upon how faster is your machine! My macbook pro will go 2Gbps + second on transfer speed. so leak will be much faster. if the system is slower the leak will grow gradually

Comment: that explains it, my receiving end does less than 100Mb (raspberry pi)

Comment: XHR objects not collecting GC? What is eating the memory! Reusing objects or null , undefined , delete , changing scope Nothing working! :(

Comment: can you see if `xhr = null;setTimeout(sendRequest, 0);` in the load callback makes any difference (again, here, due to slow server, seems ok)

Comment: Sorry! Yesterday i try the same! with 100ms, 1000ms, 3000ms timeouts , no luck! but Now i try setTimeout(sendRequest, 0); No improvement! :(

Comment: the `xhr=null` was the addition

Comment: Yes! Added that also during the test!

Answer (score 1):

Try a newer modern method, using fetch...?

```
let url = '/upload.php'
let myInit = {
    method: 'post',
    cache: 'no-store',
    body: new ArrayBuffer(2000000)
}

function sendRequest() {
    return fetch(url, myInit)
        .then(res => res.blob())
        .then(sendRequest)
}

sendRequest()
```

Comment: MDN says it is an experimental technology! IE etc. will not support it. Also i need progress handler!